# Update a php-mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a php-mysql application that tracks and displays assignments to a help desk.  It starts with a grid of assignments for the current month.

There are previous and next bars, which when clicked, display the previous or next month's assignments and this is accomplished using PHP self-submission.

I'd love to revise the application so that a click on previous or next month can be handled by jQuery's $.post() method but cant't figure out how to update my SQL statement and re-query.

The SQL statement has the form

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE monthnum = ".$monum
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look up `post()` in jQuery API, you will find a solution. you can achieve what you want by using

```
$.post('path_to_php_file_that_selects_data_from_db_and_echoes_it', function(data) {
  $('where_you_want_to_put_updated_data').html(data);
});
```

if you want to add parameters to php file, send them through `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Refer this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method.

```
$.get("get_data.php", { month: "NEXT_MONTH" } , function(data) {
```

// replace current table html or do something to show retrieved data

```
  $('view-table').html(data);

});
```

And use the GET variable 'month' to decide which month data you need to return from get_data.php file